# Time to exit Mumbai (BOM) Intl Airport (Terminal 2)

Tags: customs-and-immigration, india, international-travel, e-visas, bom

I will be travelling to Mumbai with an E-Visa and will arrive on Tuesday 10pm. My question is how long it would take to exit the airport(including immigration clearance, customs and baggage claiming)?
Recent experience of anyone with e-visa would be greatly appreciated. 
The flight is Thai Airways (Bangkok-Mumbai).

Comment: In 2016 and 2017, I was through in under 45 minutes. The queue for persons with e-Visas was very short. Most passengers either had regular visas in the passport or were Indian nationals. I may have been lucky with baggage claim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frequent traveler to BOM (Chhatrapati Shivaji International Airport) here. I would say 45 mins would be a best case scenario in BOM. My previous experiences at BOM are as follows:

1. There is always an imminent tarmac delay at BOM. You plane lands but ATC does not provide any gate for the flight causing the delay process to begin. Assume here to be ~10-20 mins delay
2. All gates are significantly far from the Customs/Immigrations and hence I would assume another ~15-20 mins walk from gate to Immigration area

Worst Part begins here:

3. If one is not an Indian National, one has to fill an immigration form AFAIK. So consider ~1-2 minutes to fill up the form
4. There are a lot of gates at the immigration checks however people keep pouring in more and more. I expect it requires ~15 minutes (best case scenario ~7 mins) to go up to the counter to the immigration officer
5. Expect ~2 mins till the immigration officer clears you and then the you are off to the baggage clearance
6. Good thing is during this time your baggage will be on the conveyors and you will save a few minutes here
7. Customs check: even if you have nothing to declare there will be a decent line at no declarations customs check where you will be asked by a Customs Officer to place a bag (handbag/check-in bag) on the conveyor for scanning. Expect ~5 mins.

All-in-all it takes one close to ~1.5 Hour from tarmac to get out of BOM. Over the years flight frequency has increased a lot and I do not see any decrease of time at BOM.

Comment: I’m assuming that the airline gives immigration card in the flight itself

Comment: I have seen some airlines do it, but for the past 2 times they don't have the forms and you can get them easily before you enter the immigration area

Answer (score 0):

I have travelled now and so I can say that it took me 45 minutes to exit the airport after landing. However there was 20 minutes delay for landing, but the flight was 30 minutes early anyways. The E-Visa queue wasn’t long and customs check and luggage collection was quick. It took me 10 minutes to walk from the gate to the immigration queue. Immigration form was provided on the flight.